# how to add div on top of image and there's issue with alignment while using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been struggling to make right alignment and responsive. i want to add some of the test on top of the image. i have try changing values in css but it doesnt work out. i want to make as it below:

codepen: [codepen link](https://codepen.io/aka/pen/yJpWPR)

Please advise. i am new to bootstrap.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background: white;">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="parent" >
                    <div class="circle">1</div>
                    <div class="expenseItems">Mobile</div>
                    <div class="hr"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="parent" >
                    <div class="circle">2</div>
                    <div class="expenseItems">Select a Product Category</div>
                    <div class="hr"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="parent" >
                    <img  src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/baby-blue-border-clipart-8748-light-blue-square-clip-art.png" class="tabimg" alt="">
                        <div class="circle tag" style="background-color:darkblue">3</div>
                        <div class="expenseItems">Find the latest software, firmware, and drivers<font color="darkblue"></font></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="parent" >
                    <div class="circle">4</div>
                    <div class="expenseItems">Tablet Use</div>
                    <div class="hr"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-left: 1px;
}
.parent {
  border: 1px;
  padding: 20px 25px 25px;
}
.circle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
.expenseItems {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.hr {
  background: gray;
  height: 2px;
} 
.tag {
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 15px;
   z-index: 1000;
   background-color: #92AD40;
   padding: 5px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.tabimg {
    padding :  0px 0px 0px 0px;  
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach to this would be just setting a background image to the div 
in question.

I've added an ID to the div you're trying to add the image to, and I added the following code for that div.

```
#box-with-image {
  background: url(http://images.clipartpanda.com/baby-blue-border-clipart-8748-light-blue-square-clip-art.png);
  background-size: contain; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /*
  OTHER OPTION:
  background-size: cover; 
  */
}
```

[Full Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/lkwatson/pen/ZOvNVd?editors=1100)

For sizing, `contain` will position the image top left, and fill whichever dimension is smallest. `cover` will fit whichever dimension is largest.

Or in other words, in a non-square shaped div, `contain` will leave whitespace, while `cover` will cut some of the image off.

Another approach to this would be using the following CSS on the image

```
img {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: how about the number and text not a line when text has more then one line of text.

Comment: Do you mean you want the div to expand so the text of that box stays in one line?

Comment: as i have attached image number 2 and there are two lines should be align and  like wise for 3 as well

Comment: @aka I'm not sure what you mean. Image number 2 where? In your code? In this post?

Comment: Tab number 2 and Select Product Category is not align. also expand the box so text tab number 3 and text "Find the latest software, firmware, and drivers" in align and cover under box as i have attached image in the question

Comment: It looks like the second column has <div class="hr"> while the third column doesn't.

Comment: third column will have text appear on image so it wont be having line.how can i make it as it like i have attached image in question

Comment: I've updated the codepen, see lines 19, 23, and 36. Note that this solution is pretty hack-ey. Take a read into using :before and :after pseudo-classes, and also consider using more inner columns.

Comment: image is not covered to whole text. i want to generate as it is as i have attached in image like tab 2 which has number 2 and two lines divided "select product" "category" . i am really thankful of yours for giving so quick response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117500/discussion-between-lucas-watson-and-aka).